# Rails json/jbuilder - Group json view based on category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, jbuilder

I have an web application maded in RoR. 
I need to provide the json to an mobile App.
This is my code to generate the Json:

```
json.category do
 json.name monument.category.name
 json.monumento do
  json.name monument.name
  json.id monument.id
  json.pois monument.pois do |p|
   json.name p.name
  end
 end
end
```

The output is:

```
{
    "category": {
        "name": "Igrejas",
        "monumento": {
            "name": "Igreja de Santa Maria do Olival",
            "id": 2,
            "pois": [{
                "name": "Igreja de Santa Maria do Olival"
            }]
        }
    }
},
{
    "category": {
        "name": "Igrejas",
        "monumento": {
            "name": "Igreja de São João Baptista",
            "id": 3,
            "pois": [{
                "name": "Igreja de São João Baptista"
            }]
        }
    }
},
{
    "category": {
        "name": "Igrejas",
        "monumento": {
            "name": "Igreja da Nossa Senhora da Graça",
            "id": 4,
            "pois": [{
                "name": "Igreja da Nossa Senhora da Graça"
            }]
        }
    }
},
```

My Problem is that i need to group the categories.

something like this:

```
{
    "category": {
        "name": "Igrejas",
        "monumento": {
            "name": "Igreja de Santa Maria do Olival",
            "id": 2,
            "pois": [{
                "name": "Igreja de Santa Maria do Olival"
            }]
        },
        "monumento": {
            "name": "Igreja de São João Baptista",
            "id": 3,
            "pois": [{
                "name": "Igreja de São João Baptista"
            }]
        },

        "monumento": {
            "name": "Igreja da Nossa Senhora da Graça",
            "id": 4,
            "pois": [{
                "name": "Igreja da Nossa Senhora da Graça"
            }]
        }
    }
},
```

Any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Your second example is a not valid json format. You can't do output like this.

Comment: I dont understand, my outrput is not valid?

Comment: I want to agroup the categories. I Have 4 types of categories and have 24 diferent monuments. How can i do that?

Comment: how are monuments and categories associated? what is the query you do to get the data in your controller?

Comment: Categories has_many monuments. And monuments belogs_to categories.
What controller and what action?

Comment: This does not sound like a JSON issue, but an issue of how to create a Ruby Hash/Array which can then be converted in to JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like this

In your controller,

```
@categories = Category.where(name: 'Igrejas').includes(monuments: :pois)
```

In your view,

```
json.category @categories do |category|
  json.name category.name
  json.monuments category.monuments do |monument|
    json.name monument.name
    json.id monument.id
    json.pois monument.pois do |p|
      json.name p.name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In the action index?

Comment: but i have already this in index action :  @categories = Category.all

Comment: replace that with `Category.includes(monuments: :pois)` because your query is n+1